# how can i get out of vi editor when esc won't work?

Tags: unix, cygwin, vi

I am using vi editor for UNIX.  Sometimes I am experiencing an issue with getting out of vi editor, where I go to press esc then type ":wq" or "q!" to quit, but it is not escaping.  vi editor just enters weird symbols/characters and I can't get out. What do I do to escape and exit when esc won't escape?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone.  I hope no one else has to battle with this primitive editor.  I ended up just switching over to using pico instead, it's MUCH easier to use, I didn't have the bugging out problems with pico that I had with vi.

Comment: Given the myriad of editors available, I wonder why you did use vi, if you don't like it.

Answer (score 19):

There are few more commands for that apart from the one you are using

1. Shift+zz to save (if modified )and exit
2. :cq quit without writing

EDIT : 
I found some more commands that I just learned .

There are many ways to exit from vi editors, and you can use some of these commands to exit from other editors

3. Press F2, this will drop you in Insert Mode, now press: q and hit enter
4. another way is to press Ctrl + c or ctrl + z command to exit the vi editor forcefully.
5. press ZZ (shift+z+z). it will save and exit.
6. Ctrl + [ will also work like escape key.

the 3rd , and 6th command may or may not work on every system, as it depends on terminal's setting and system itself.

or you can do map certain keys to behave like escape, please refer this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93144/exit-vim-more-quickly) , that will save you some keystrokes.

Answer (score 16):

For me this worked:
CTL + c (this is equal to ESC in your case)
:wq! (to write save and quit) and then click enter

Comment: For those who don't want to add changes, just use :q! instead of :wq!

Answer (score 5):

have you tried ESC then "ZZ"?
seems to work as a last result for me.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when vi is started with TERM=linux. You can use the set term command to solve this problem.
Set the TERM to vt100 with one of the following commands depending on the shell.

```
csh or tcsh:        setenv TERM vt100
sh:                 TERM=vt100; export TERM
ksh, bash, or zsh:  export TERM=vt100
```

vi should work without setting the terminal in  kx mode(refer to this for a similar issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86742/term-linuxxterm-vi-in-an-xterm-or-the-aaabbbbbbccddd-problem).
In order to save this, add the set TERM command to ~/.vimrc file so the option is loaded when starting vi.

Comment: Does Unicode work when wie have the TERM set to _vt100_? And why do we want to do a terminal emulation from the Stone Age? Shouldn't `TERM=xterm` work as well? (This would be Iron Age at least).

Comment: Whether Unicode works or not is a separate discussion; the `TERM` variable ony really governs how some control and escape codes etc are interpreted. What exactly works on which platform is a somewhat more complex topic; `xterm` arguably offers a broader feature set, but might not be as widely supported.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ^z followed by "kill" the process?

Answer (score -1):

I just had this issue with editor of command line of Git Bash and what worked was press `Esc` and then `:q!`. When I typed only `q!`, it did not work.

Answer (score -2):

press the following shift + esc
look at bottom left corner
write the following colon included :wq

Comment: Why do you think shift is necessary?

Comment: THATS WHAT WORKS FOR ME. he clearly said just typing esc wasn't working for him.....

Comment: And I'm trying to prod as to under which circumstances this could be useful or necessary. Which platform are you on? Does shift+Esc generally do something different than just Esc? Do you have a regional keyboard layout where plain Esc is not available, and always requires shifting?

Comment: just pressing esc doesn't work for me. I've always used shift esc :wq